# How to shift a right-alighned text block to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a right-aligned text (in a right-to-left language) and need to shift it to the left (it is actually a signature under the preface of a book).

if I use `flushleft` environment, it goes to the left but it also becomes left-aligned while I need to have it right-aligned something like below:

```
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
           ----------
------
  ----
 -----
```

Comment: Do you know how to place material in a `minipage` environment? Inside the `minipage`, you could choose flush-right alignment for the RTL language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a `tabular` environment to keep the text-alignment and then shifted it to the left inside a `flushleft` enviornment.

```
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular} {r}
 احمد پورامینی \\
  دانشگاه صنعتی سیرجان \\
  خرداد 1395
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
```